# What options for y axis line style exist in TikZ/PGFPlots?

Tags: pgfplots, tikz-arrows

I am plotting following graph of a function and **I would like to have arrows pointing upwards and downwards.**

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    minor tick num=0,
    axis y line=left,
    axis x line=middle,
    width=\textwidth,
    height=0.5*\textwidth,
    %xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$\sin x$,
    yticklabels=\empty,
    xticklabels=\empty,
    ymax=7.5,
    ymin=-7.5,
    y axis line style={stealth}
]
    \addplot[smooth,black,mark=none,dotted,
    domain=0:31.4159,samples=1000]
        { cos(deg(x))};
    \addplot[smooth,blue,mark=none, dotted, domain=0:31.4159,samples=1000]
        { 0.5 * ( (3/8)*x*cos(deg(x)) - (9/32)*sin(deg(x)) - (1/32) * sin(3*deg(x))  )};
    \addplot[smooth,red,mark=none, domain=0:31.4159,samples=1000]
        { cos(deg(x)) + 0.5 * ( (3/8)*x*cos(deg(x)) - (9/32)*sin(deg(x)) - (1/32) * sin(3*deg(x))  )};
\end{axis}fasdf
\end{tikzpicture}
```

gives following picture

[image]

p.132 of [https://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~simardr/pgfplots.pdf](https://www.iro.umontreal.ca/%7Esimardr/pgfplots.pdf) it says

```
y axis line style={〈key-value-list〉}
```

Are there any default options? This question sounds stupid, but where can I find the "key-value-list" ? I tried to search for this in the same manual, but I cannot find anything about this.

Any hint or help is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Well, any one you want and [TikZ will understand](https://tikz.dev/tikz-actions), for example `<->` or `stealth-stealth` or `draw=grey, <-, dashed`. With your setup, the default is `-stealth` for `every outer y axis line` (which you can obscurely check by doing `every outer y axis line/.show code`). The [`y axis line style`](https://tikz.dev/pgfplots/reference-styleoptions#autosec-6914) only appends the key-value-list to `every outer y axis line` (and also inner).

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel What does TikZ understand? Where can I find those commands? I would not ask, if I could find these. Thank you!

Comment: Look in the PGF/Ti*k*Z manual for the basic options. `pgfplots` is built on top, so you can also, in many cases, use standard `pgf`/`tikz` key-value options.

Comment: I did look into the manual, but I cannot find it. Where is it?

Comment: The default option are documented [in the manual](https://tikz.dev/pgfplots/reference-axisdescription#sec-20.9) as well (look for `every non boxed` …).

Comment: By the way, the manual you linked to is thirteen years old. That's ancient. Try to use the one provided by your TeX distribution (`texdoc pgfplots`) or the online service [texdoc.org](texdoc.org/serve/pgfplots/0) or even the inofficial online version tikz.dev/pgfplots.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I am very new to TikZ and did not realise that I am not looking at the official manual. Thank you for all the help, it worked out now!